# UIButton swizzling causing issue with UITableViewCellAccessoryType's

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitableview, swizzling

I have a class that swizzles `UIButton`'s when the `buttonType` is `UIButtonTypeCustom` is true.
However, this is also true when it comes to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosure` is used as well. What is happening is that for some reason, it is swizzling them and adding the custom background and so forth behind the `accessoryType` for some reason.

What I need to do is to check whether or not the `UIButton` that I'm trying to swizzle is a `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` but I am unaware of how to do such a thing.

Here's the innards of the function that I am using to swizzle the `UIButton`.

```
if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]] && self.buttonType == UIButtonTypeCustom) {

        UIImage *upImage = [theme rectButtonUp], *downImage = [theme rectButtonDown];
        UIColor *upColor = [theme rectButtonUpTextColor], *downColor = [theme rectButtonDownTextColor];

        /* If the highlighted title is set to _theme_asdf, look for a custom
         * button image called "asdf" and use that. Clear out this highlighted
         * title string. */

        NSString *hlTitle = [self titleForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        if ([hlTitle isEqualToString:@"_theme_add"] || [hlTitle isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {
            upImage = [theme rectButtonUpAdd];
            downImage = [theme rectButtonDownAdd];
        } else if ([hlTitle isEqualToString:@"_theme_remove"]) {
            upImage = [theme rectButtonUpRemove];
            downImage = [theme rectButtonDownRemove];
        } else {
            upImage = [theme rectButtonUp];
            downImage = [theme rectButtonDown];
        }

        [self setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        upColor = [theme rectButtonUpTextColor];
        downColor = [theme rectButtonDownTextColor];

        [self setBackgroundImage:upImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setBackgroundImage:downImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self setBackgroundImage:downImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        if (upColor) {
            [self setTitleColor:upColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self setTitleColor:[upColor colorByLighteningTo:0.5f] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        }
        if (downColor) {
            [self setTitleColor:downColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [self setTitleColor:downColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: subclass the UIButton and use that class when you want to swizzle it so that you only swizzle your new class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix that I have done that accomplishes what I wanted to achieve.

Code:
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]] && self.buttonType == UIButtonTypeCustom) {

```
    if (![[self titleLabel] text]) {

    } else {

        UIImage *upImage = [theme rectButtonUp], *downImage = [theme rectButtonDown];
        UIColor *upColor = [theme rectButtonUpTextColor], *downColor = [theme rectButtonDownTextColor];

        /* If the highlighted title is set to _theme_asdf, look for a custom
         * button image called "asdf" and use that. Clear out this highlighted
         * title string. */

        NSString *hlTitle = [self titleForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        if ([hlTitle isEqualToString:@"_theme_add"] || [hlTitle isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {
            upImage = [theme rectButtonUpAdd];
            downImage = [theme rectButtonDownAdd];
        } else if ([hlTitle isEqualToString:@"_theme_remove"]) {
            upImage = [theme rectButtonUpRemove];
            downImage = [theme rectButtonDownRemove];
        } else {
            upImage = [theme rectButtonUp];
            downImage = [theme rectButtonDown];
        }

        [self setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        upColor = [theme rectButtonUpTextColor];
        downColor = [theme rectButtonDownTextColor];

        [self setBackgroundImage:upImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setBackgroundImage:downImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self setBackgroundImage:downImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        if (upColor) {
            [self setTitleColor:upColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self setTitleColor:[upColor colorByLighteningTo:0.5f] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        }
        if (downColor) {
            [self setTitleColor:downColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [self setTitleColor:downColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
    }   
}
```

So, basically, all of the `UIButtons` have a `titleLabel` with `text` but the `UITableViewCellAccessoryType`'s don't. Therefore, we have success. It may be a hack but for now it has aided me in completing what I need.